# vba Excel using a declared variable in another sub

Tags: vba, excel

What I'm trying to do here is use my declared "vSelection" in another Sub but it doesn't seem to be working. Maybe anyone can help me out?

This is where I declare it.

```
Public Sub cmdBladeren_Click()
```

```
Dim vSelection As Variant
vSelection = Application.GetOpenFilename("Graphics files (*.gif), *.gif")
```

```
If vSelection = False Then
MsgBox "Selecteer een foto!"
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

This is where I want to use it

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()

Dim rngRange As Range
Dim rngProduct As Range
Dim lTop As Long
Dim lLeft As Long
Dim oShape As Shape   

Set rngRange = Range("C2:O100")

For intteller = 1 To 7000

If rngRange.Cells(intteller).Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80) Then
    Set rngProduct = rngRange.Cells(intteller)
    rngProduct.Interior.Color = RGB(193, 130, 67)
    lTop = rngProduct.Top
    lLeft = rngProduct.Left
```

```
    Set oShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(vSelection, True, True,   lLeft, lTop, 100, 192)
```

```
rngProduct.Offset(1, 0).Value = Me.txtNaamProduct.Value
Exit For
Else
End If

Next
Unload frmNieuwProduct

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to declare `vSelection` **before** the first procedure and not in it.

Comment: That did the trick, ty :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the scope of the variable

Scope   How the variable is declared

Procedure only - By using a Dim or a Static statement in the procedure that uses the variable

Module only - By using a Dim statement before the first Sub or Function statement in the module

All procedures in all modules - By using a Public statement before the first Sub or Function statement in a module